# Lost in pointerworld, write to variable via array

Tags: c++, pointers, avr

I'm a bit lost in pointer-world :-)
Read a value by using passing a number to readSystemVal works like a charm, but now I would like to write to these variables using writeSystemVal.

Can't really find what i'm supposed to do:
*systemVal is holding the adress to the variable but how do I write my value to it?

Would you be so kind to have a look?

(system: AVR, eclipse, atmega644)

```
// User Changeable variables
uint8_t     MIDIchan1 = 0;      // midichannel  osc 1
uint8_t     MIDIchan2 = 1;      // midichannel  osc 2
uint8_t     MIDIchan3 = 2;      // midichannel  osc 3
uint8_t     pbRange = 12;       // pitchbend
uint8_t     omniModus = 0x00;   // 3 osc modus or 1 omni modus 
uint8_t     midiThru = 0x01;    // midiTrhu on/off
uint8_t     *systemValList[] = {&MIDIchan1, &MIDIchan2, &MIDIchan3, &pbRange, &omniModus, &midiThru};


//**************************************************
// readSystemVal
// DESCRIPTION:
//  Hele simpele note off routine
//**************************************************
uint8_t readSystemVal (uint8_t systemItem)
{
    uint8_t *systemVal = (uint8_t *)systemValList[(uint8_t)systemItem];
    uint8_t returnVal = *systemVal;

    return returnVal;
}

void writeSystemVal (uint8_t ctrlValue, uint8_t systemItem)
{
/*
    uint8_t *systemVal = (uint8_t *)systemValList[(uint8_t)systemItem];
    //uint8_t returnVal = *systemVal;
    // systemVal = ctrlValue;
*/
}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `*systemVal = ctrlValue;`?

Comment: Casting things to the types they already have only introduces clutter and potential for future bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `systemVal` (without the asterisk) is holding the address. That's what pointers are, just an integer whose value is the address the pointer points to.

You use the dereference operator `*` for both reading and writing the value a pointer points to.

Example, returning the value a pointer points to:

```
return *systemVal;
```

Example, set the value a pointer points to:

```
*systemVal = ctrlValue;
```

---

By the way, the `readSystemVal` function can be shortened to this:

```
uint8_t readSystemVal (uint8_t systemItem)
{
    return *systemValList[systemItem];
}
```

No need for the extra steps in between. And especially not the typecasting, which is casting the values to the types they actually are declared to be.